# Cannot install Popcorn-Time

Tags: software-installation

I downloaded the Popcorn-Time from official link. When I try to execute "Popcorn-Time" file, using `./Popcorn-Time`, it outputs the following error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've tried installing `libudev0` by using:

```
apt-get install libudev0:i386
```

But that outputs the following error:

```
E: Package 'libudev0:i386' has no installation candidate
```

The image below contains all extracted files from .tar:
[image]

Anyone knows how I can execute Popcorn?

Comment: You say that you downloaded PT from "official link" yet you give no link. How do you expect anyone to help you? There are multiple forks of PT and it's impossible to help you without knowing exactly which one you are trying to run.

Comment: This looks like the same problem as [How to run/use popcorn-time?](https://askubuntu.com/q/433997) That question mentions the source distribution but the answers apply to the binary one. The version you're installing expects `libudev.so.0`, which would be provided by the `libudev0` package but no recent versions of Ubuntu has that package. All recent releases have the `libudev1` instead, which provides `libudev.so.1`. You will almost surely prefer to use a newer version of the software, with which you won't have this problem, but that question should make it possible to install this version.

Answer (score 1):

If you're still trying to figure it out. I managed to get mine to work after a lot of fiddling. I did grab the source from here https://popcorntime.sh/ then I used the commands Ramesh posted earlier. I did not use the final part though and just checked the extracted folder. You would see that there's a file in the folder called Popcorn Time. Drag and drop to terminal and it should work flawlessly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If `popcorntime.sh` is the source he already used it's impossible this answer is correct. From his output you can see that he clearly is missing a library, which this answer does nothing to resolve. If he got it from somewhere else, it's possible this works because `popcorntime.sh` somehow bundles the library or is dependent on another library (that is installed).

Answer (score 0):

`libudev0:i386` does not look like the name of an ubuntu package. What happens if you run:

```
sudo apt-get install libudev0
```

Please supply the full output in your original question if this does not resolve your issue.

In the future, you can Google "libudev0:i386 ubuntu package" and you will see from the results that the name is in fact `libudev0`.

Comment: `libudev0:i386` means the `libudev0` package for the i386 architecture (32-bit PCs). The amd64 versions of Ubuntu (for 64-bit PCs) can install i386 packages. In recent releases it works out of the box with this syntax. The problem isn't that `libudev0` must be installed instead of `libudev0:i386`, but that current releases have [`libudev1`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libudev1&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) instead. See this [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747108/cannot-install-popcorn-time#comment1501679_747108) and [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/433997).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I'll leave my (incorrect) answer as-is and mark it as community wiki in case someone wants to improve it.