# How to uninstall Popcorn-Time installed with a script?

Tags: scripts

I've installed Popcorn Time using the following command:

```
cd
wget https://raw.github.com/hotice/webupd8/master/popcorn-build
chmod +x popcorn-build
./popcorn-build
```

that I [found here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-popcorn-time-from-source.html).

How can I uninstall it?

Comment: This will involve a lot of command line stuff, there is no easy way to uninstall, are you sure you need to? Any particular reason not to just leave it alone?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since this is [my script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433444/install-popcorn-time) ([rewritten](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-popcorn-time-from-source.html) a bit by Webupd8's Andrew), this should work :

- uninstalling Popcorn Time :

  ```
  sudo rm -r /opt/Popcorn-Time
  sudo rm /usr/share/pixmaps/popcorntime.png
  sudo rm /usr/share/applications/popcorn-time.desktop
  sudo rm /usr/bin/popcorn-time
  ```
- remove the NodeJS

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:chris-lea/node.js
  sudo apt-get remove nodejs
  sudo rm /usr/bin/node
  ```
- remove Ruby :

  - if 12.04 : `sudo apt-get remove rubygem`
  - if 13.04 or higher : `sudo apt-get remove ruby-compass`
- remove Git, NPM :

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove git npm
  ```
- remove 'libudev' symlink :

  - if 32 bits : `sudo rm /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0`
  - if 64 bits : `sudo rm /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0`

---

Once it's done, you can clean up :

```
sudo apt-get autoremove -y
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: +1 for answering this! However, I was reading through your script and it also does things like installing a ppa which should maybe be undone, it also installs `ruby-compoass` (or `compass` if the OP is on 12.04), `git`, it runs ` npm install -g grunt-cli` and creates links in `/lib` for `libudev` and perhaps other things, I only glanced at it. Could you add instructions on how to revert those steps too please?

Comment: Apparently `npm` doesn't include a remove option, so I'm guessing all installed dependencies through it will be remove along with it. I edited looking at the modified script, so I think now the machine would be clean of all modifications.

Comment: And I'd love to give you a second upvote but... Thanks!